# Is there a way to run a script when a change in state of any service occurs?

Tags: linux, systemd, services

I would like to hook into the state of services running so that when an important service is stopped, I can run a script to either notify me or take a predefined action to recover the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not *any* service.  The dbus interface for systemd's manager doesn't provide that type of global notification.  If you're looking for signals that will trigger on a global scale, the manager's signals are a little limited, possibly for performance reasons:

```
$ busctl introspect org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1 \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager \
    | grep signal
.JobNew                                   signal    uos              -                -
.JobRemoved                               signal    uoss             -                -
.Reloading                                signal    b                -                -
.StartupFinished                          signal    tttttt           -                -
.UnitFilesChanged                         signal    -                -                -
.UnitNew                                  signal    so               -                -
.UnitRemoved                              signal    so               -                -
```

Full interface avaialble here:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html

However, if you want to know if a specific service has changed state, you can subscribe to that specific service.  Example: sshd.service:

```
$ busctl introspect \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sshd_2eservice \
    org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties 
NAME                            TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE FLAGS
.Get                            method    ss        v            -
.GetAll                         method    s         a{sv}        -
.Set                            method    ssv       -            -
.PropertiesChanged              signal    sa{sv}as  -            -
```

The `.PropertiesChanged` signal is emitted whenever a property changes.

The property you are probably interested in is `.ActiveState` or `.SubState` on the `org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit` interface.

```
$ busctl introspect \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1 \
    /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sshd_2eservice \
    org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit
...
.ActiveState    property  s         "active"         emits-change
.SubState       property  s         "running"        emits-change
```

So how would you subscribe and get that data? I'm not sure how to script it, but I would write something up in C using the sd-bus API (`#include <systemd/sd-bus.h>`).  This requires the following steps:

- Open the bus:

```
int r = sd_bus_default_system(&m_bus);
```

- Subscribe to changes on some units:

```
    sd_bus_match_signal(
        m_bus,
        NULL, // slot
        NULL, // sender
        "/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sshd_2eservice", // path
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties", // interface
        "PropertiesChanged", // member
        callback, // callback
        NULL // userdata
    );

    sd_bus_match_signal(
        m_bus,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        "/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/network_2etarget",
        "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
        "PropertiesChanged",
        callback,
        NULL
    );
```

- React to changes and get new state:

```
int callback(sd_bus_message *m, void *userdata, sd_bus_error *ret_error)
{
    sd_bus_error err = SD_BUS_ERROR_NULL;
    char* msg = NULL;
    int r;

    r = sd_bus_get_property_string(m_bus,
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1",
        sd_bus_message_get_path(m), // (/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sshd_2eservice)
        "org.freedesktop.systemd1.Unit",
        "ActiveState",
        &err,
        &msg);

    if (r < 0) { /* Error */ }

    sd_bus_error_free(&err);

    printf("Property change, state is: %s\n", msg);
    free (msg);
}
```

There is a related answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940461/how-to-get-the-state-of-a-service-with-sd-bus/62038047#62038047

Answer (score 0):

A simple possibility is to just tail the journald output, `journalctl -f`. There are various output formatting options including json for easier parsing.